# Why are objects no longer injured?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

Reading old books I have found sentences like this:-

> The reply of the Austrian batteries did no damage, and two submarines
>   that came out were accounted for at the cost of *injury* to one of the
>   British cruisers, which, however, did not put it out of action. [Manchester Guardian History of the War, 1919]

and

> The eight o'clock train ran into the experimental train and *injured*
>   three of the carriages very much. [Henry Gibbs' diary (26th Sept 1838) quoted in Red for Danger, L.T.C. Rolt]

To my modern ear this sounds absurd; the notion of the carriages being *injured very much* rather archaic.

Of the definitions of the word [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/injury) only one of them (the American Heritage Dictionary) even mentions the possibility of things:-

> 1. Damage or harm done to or suffered by a person **or thing**: escaped from the accident without injury; a scandal that did considerable
>      injury to the campaign.

but the things used as examples are all abstract; reputation, a campaign, and so forth.

So, when and why did *injury* stop being applied to concrete objects?

Comment: Books are sometimes "hurt." https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=injured+the+ships%2Cinjured+the+house%2Cinjured+the+trees%2Churt+the+house%2Churt+the+trees%2Churt+the+car%2Churt+the+book%2Churt+books&year_start=1930&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinjured%20the%20ships%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinjured%20the%20house%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinjured%20the%20trees%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Churt%20the%20house%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Churt%20the%20trees%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Churt%20the%20car%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Churt%20the%20book%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Churt%20books%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=injured+the+ships%2Cinjured+the+house%2Cinjured+the+carriage%2Cinjured+the+trees&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinjured%20the%20ships%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinjured%20the%20house%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinjured%20the%20trees%3B%2Cc0) would seem to indicate that the usage has been very rare since the late 1930s, except with 'trees', which usage fell off in the late 60s. An Ngram for 'injured the horse' shows that this is, as expected, more commonly used than the examples in the linked Ngrams (though even this usage is falling off).